# How Do I Play a Random WAV. Sample From A Folder in Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wav, gpio

I am wondering how to randomly play a wav sample from a file. I would like the randomly picked wav sample to be played when the a button tapped. So far this is what I have.

```
import pygame.mixer 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pygame.mixer.init()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BMC)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

drum = pygame.mixer.Sound("samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav")

def play(pin):
    print("playing")
    drum.play()

GPIO.add_event_detect(2, GPIO.FALLING, play, 1000)

print("ready")

while True:
    pass
```

The python code above plays a wav sample I selected when a button is pushed. How can I amend this code to make it play a random wav sample from a file when button is pushed?

Comment: A random audio sample from a WAV file, or a randomly-sampled WAV file from a folder?

Comment: I apologies for the ambiguity. I need a randomly-sampled wav file from a folder.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `glob` to compile a list of the files in the directory, then using `random.choice` to select the file. Something like this added to your code (or in the case of play(), amended):

```
import glob
import random

soundfiles = glob.glob("samples/*.wav")

def play(pin):
    print("playing")
    pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(soundfiles)).play()
```

Comment: You never called play.

Comment: `pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(soundfiles)).play()`[-6:]

Comment: What do I put in place of  the ("samples/*.wav")? Or how do I properly list wav samples after the ("samples/ how do I list the samples here")?

Comment: `glob.glob` creates a list of all the files specified in a directory. By using the wildcard `*`, we are choosing all the wave files in the samples/ directory. If you wish to use a subdirectory, then follow a similar procedure: `glob.glob("samples/directory1/directory11/directory111/*.wav")`. Or, if you want only some of a particular type, `glob.glob("samples/timpani*.wav")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir` to get all the files in the folder.

```
import os, random

def play():
    files=os.listdir('.')
    file=random.choice(files)
    pygame.mixer.Sound(file).play()
    print("playing")
```

If you want wav's, you can add this line:

```
files=filter(lambda f: f.endswith(".wav"), files)
```